# How do I fix an error: Unknown plugin "flow-react-proptypes" in react native?

Tags: babeljs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to use https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-action-sheet-component in a react-native project and am getting the following runtime error

> Unknown plugin "flow-react-proptypes" specified in
>   "node_modules/react-native-action-sheet-component/.babelrc.env.development

I tried `yarn add babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes -D` but that didn't seem to fix it.

React-native version 0.41.2, iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with yarn but from that repo packaje.json we can see that babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes is listed as devDependency so it won't get installed when installing the package from npm.

Try installing it in your node_modules folder (if that's not what you already did with yarn) or go into node_modules/react-native... And execute npm install.